# Cartesian Product and Set Difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve the following question:
[image]

And I could do with your help.

I have started by saying that on the left side, we have a set of all ordered pairs (x,y) such that x belongs to C and y belongs to D, and, x doesn't belong to A **or** y doesn't belong to B. Am I on the right way? How to proceed from here?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990222/a-subseteq-x-and-b-subseteq-y-show-that-x-times-y-setminus-a-times and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654474/show-that-a-1-times-b-1-setminusa-2-times-b-2-a-1-cap-a-2-times-b-1-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have started by saying that on the left side, we have a set of all ordered pairs (x,y) such that x belongs to C and y belongs to D, and, x doesn't belong to A or y doesn't belong to B. Am I on the right way? How to proceed from here?

Yes.   That is a good start.   Next, *carefully choose* to distribute the first conjunct over the second conjunct.

$\quad(C\times D)\setminus(A\times B) \\=\{(x,y):(x\in C\,\wedge\, y\in D)\wedge(\color{navy}{x\notin A\,\vee\, y\notin B})\} \\ = \{(x,y): (x\in C\,\wedge\, y\in D\,\wedge\,\color{navy}{ x\notin A})\color{navy}{\vee}(x\in C\,\wedge\, y\in D\,\wedge\, \color{navy}{y\notin B}) \}$

From here things should be clear.

In words: ... Meaning we have a set of ordered pairs, $(x,y)$, where $x$ belongs to $C$ but not to $A$ and $y$ belongs to $D$, OR $x$ belongs to $C$ and $y$ belongs to $D$ but not to $B$.